# What kind of berries are these purple and reddish with crown looking tops?

Tags: colorado, plant-identification

There are some 15ft tall shrubs/trees that have these purple and reddish of berries. The trees seem to be either 15ft tall or 3ft and they are growing next to a trail. The tree wood is a greyish brown and smooth.

[image]

Does anyone know what kind of berries these are and if they are edible?

Answer (score 4):

These are not blueberry - the leaves would be smooth and the fruits would be covered in a pale whiteish wax bloom. Although they do look very similar to blueberry in the washed fruit form as you might buy at the supermarket.

However, good news - these are most likely [Serviceberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelanchier_alnifolia) (*Amelanchier alnifolia*). Also known as Saskatoon (after which the Canadian state of Saskatchewan is named and the city of Saskatoon too). They are edible and very common in Alaska, Western Canada and the North and West of the USA.

Comment: I concur.  They are a Juneberries, also known as Serviceberries. They are edible, raw or cooked.

Answer (score 0):

The leaves and berries look like a blueberry, probably a highbush blueberry from your description. If that's the case, they are edible. I'm not familiar enough with Colorado vegetation to know if there are any poisonous lookalikes in the area.